# Do we allow Fan Fictions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just stumbled upon a question tagged with [hp-methods-of-rationality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hp-methods-of-rationality) and I found that there are handful of questions on that tag.

Do we allow Fan Fictions?

If yes, can I discuss a fan fiction told by my friend last evening? Certainly not. What are the criteria for the fan fictions to be allowed here?

If no, I request the community and moderators to do some clean ups.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/how-to-handle-fan-fiction-answers But these are a bit old so I guess it wouldn't be terrible to revisit this.

Comment: @Ixrec Please don't post https links to meta.scifi. There's a certificate issue there.

Comment: To address a specific point in the question, I think it should be a published fan fiction.

Comment: @SQB What does 'publishing' mean here, when the internet exists?  The only published-via-a-publisher fan fiction are going to be things like *The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen*, i.e. stories about 100+ year-old works.

Comment: @Keen I was addressing the point in the question about "a fan fiction told by my friend last evening". That's not published.

Comment: @Keen There's an argument to be made that being posted on a fan fiction forum counts as self-publishing. I think a better way to word it would be that the material would have to be freely available. Asking about a story your friend made up and told you last night would be pointless since nobody else on the site would 1. know what you're on about and 2. be able to verify the accuracy of any information posted to answer it.